# Reducing the size of .so library

Tags: c++, optimization, g++, compiler-flags

I have given a task to optimize the performance of a program (Both ROM and RAM size). I am the idea click to me is to use -Os inside of -O2 to reduce the .so size. Does this will effect the performance of my program?

I am using `strip` the library already.

What can be the other optimization can i check for?

Comment: `strip` unused symbols ? the flag for this under `gcc` it's `-s`

Comment: there's probably better things you can do to optimize a program than play with compiler flags

Comment: sure there are better things than compiler/linker flags, the source code it's always the first thing to optimize, that's for sure. But sometimes a strip can save a good portion of space.

Comment: `strip` would not remove the export section. A reasonable way to get rid of the unused symbols is `ld` version script: http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_25.html

Comment: I am sorry to mention after strip already.